# Restricting input field characters to specific sequence of numbers and dashes in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I was wondering if there is a way for PHP to take a string and determine whether it follows a specific pattern of numbers and dashes.  For instance, can it check to make sure that that the user inputs 00-00-000-000?  So it would be two numbers, hyphen, two numbers, hyphen, three numbers, hyphen, three numbers.

Comment: You tagged your question with `regex`, so you seem to already know the answer.

Comment: (If you are unsure of the reason for the downvotes: Here on Stack Overflow we have a widespread expectation of prior effort and research, especially for problems that, having already effectively been broken down into pieces of work, just require the use of the manual to discover the answer. It is often thought that, in such cases, handing over the answer has two negative results: (1) the site gets a reputation as a place where free work can be obtained for no effort, and (2) the original poster does not learn anything. Hope this explanation helps.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using anubhava's regex, here is the php:

```
if (preg_match("/^\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{3}$/", $string))
{
    //the string is good
} else {
    //the string is bad
    die("Invalid string entered");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can match with this regex:

```
/^\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{3}$/
```

Comment: Couldn't see why just the piggy back answer should get all the credit.